# Python: How to do approximate comparison or add certain level of tolerance in a value for comparison

Tags: python, excel

i have 2 excel files with existing values, i need to compare these values and show their status (Pass/Fail) , these values are sometimes approximate to each other, for e.g. 4.7 & 5 or 7 & 7.3. How do i add tolerance so that close proximity test case does not Fail.
Excel 1: 2.3,   4.3, 10.1,  22.2

Excel 2:  2,   4,  10,  22

Is there any way so that i can add a range within so that i can compare for approximate values?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but it might be of some help. 
You can define your own comparison function and use it with `.apply()` to compare columns of dataframe or just two elements

```
import pandas as pd

def equal_or_similar(x,y,threshold=0.2):
    return(abs(x-y)<threshold)

equal_or_similar(1,1.1) 
## Returns true 

items= [('x', [ 1,2,3,3,3,5,9,10,11,13]), ('y',[1.1,1.5,31,1,1,4.9,4,1,11,12])]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_items(items)


df.apply(lambda row : equal_or_similar(row[0],row[1]),axis=1)
```